# SSL(https) for multiple domains with 1 shared IP address

Tags: ssl, https, ip, cpanel

We have a cPanel having more then 100 ADD-ON domains hosted with 1 shared IP Address.We are planing to integrate SSL(https) for FEW/ALL of them. Is it possible? If yes, please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The [Server Name Indication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-3) TLS extension enables virtual domains hosted on a single IP address.  It is supported by all modern browsers and all popular TLS libraries.

In most server software, provided the underlying TLS library supports SNI, no additional configuration is needed beyond what you would already have to support virtual domain (i.e. the DNS name(s) of the server(s)).  So there's a fair chance that you're already good to go, and all you have to do is configure the keys and certificates.

Answer (score -1):

To qualify for an SSL you need to fulfill certain requirements, one of which is the domain needs a dedicated IP. If you want the SSL per domain you will need separate IP's for each. However, if they are stores you can setup a wildcard SSL certificate for your domain and have sub domains for each of the websites. This means that when a customer goes to the SSL secured part of the site the URL will change to *website.yourdomain.com*. If that isn't a problem, then that is probably your best bet. If not, you will need to speak to your ISP or support company to try and get more dedicated IP's.

Comment: "you will need separate IP's for each [domain]" is no longer true, due to SNI which is widely supported.